# Create a new RGB OpenCV image using Python?

Tags: python, opencv

Using OpenCV in Python, how can I create a new RGB image? I don't want to load the image from a file, just create an empty image ready to work with.

Comment: If I may question the duplicate flag, one question is being answered with cv, and the other with cv2.

Comment: we need a way to merge questions on stack overflow

Comment: to be fair, 8 years later, they both have cv2 answers :)

Comment: I reopened this. Aside from any question about library version: if anything, this should be the canonical for the how-to question - it's much more popular and better received. The other question was phrased as a debugging question, whereas OP here did not encounter any kind of error. The one good answer here also seems higher quality, as it offers better explanation and a relevant documentation link.

Comment: For context: this was previously marked as a duplicate of [OpenCv CreateImage Function isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710520), under the old duplicate closure system.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

The new `cv2` interface for Python integrates [numpy](https://numpy.org/) arrays into the OpenCV framework, which makes operations much simpler as they are represented with simple multidimensional arrays.  For example, your question would be answered with:

```
import cv2  # Not actually necessary if you just want to create an image.
import numpy as np
blank_image = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)
```

This initialises an RGB-image that is just black.  Now, for example, if you wanted to set the left half of the image to blue and the right half to green , you could do so easily:

```
blank_image[:,0:width//2] = (255,0,0)      # (B, G, R)
blank_image[:,width//2:width] = (0,255,0)
```

If you want to save yourself a lot of trouble in future, as well as having to ask questions such as this one, I would strongly recommend using the `cv2` interface rather than the older `cv` one.  I made the change recently and have never looked back.  You can read more about `cv2` at the [OpenCV Change Logs](https://web.archive.org/web/20130815041744/http://opencv.willowgarage.com:80/wiki/OpenCV%20Change%20Logs).

Comment: You don't need to `import cv2` in your example?

Comment: No, it isn't necessary.  It's just to make it clear that with cv2 there's nothing special about an image --- it's just a numpy array.

Comment: A lesson I have learned well today.... :)

Comment: V good point - could you possibly highlight that point in the question? Would be quite useful I think :)

Comment: I clarified the import @jtlz2

Comment: to get RGB color check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710520/opencv-createimage-function-isnt-working

Comment: what does the 3 stand for?  np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)

Comment: @mattsmith5 The 3 represents the three color channels: blue, green, and red.

Comment: One chanel blank image: blank=255*cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (100,100)) . For RGB use cv2.merge(). :–)

Answer (score 4):

The following code shows creating a blank RGB image and displaying it:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

height, width = 1080, 1920
b, g, r = 0x3E, 0x88, 0xE5  # orange
image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
image[:, :, 0] = b
image[:, :, 1] = g
image[:, :, 2] = r

cv2.imshow("A New Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: useful because you can fill it with any color