# create a multichannel zeros mat in python with cv2

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

i want to create a multichannel mat object in python with cv2 opencv wrapper.

i've found examples on the net where the c++ Mat::zeros is replaced with numpy.zeros, that seems good. but no multichannel type seems to fit..

look at the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

size = 200, 200
m = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.uint8) # ?
m = cv2.cvtColor(m, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
p1 = (0,0)
p2 = (200, 200)
cv2.line(m, p1, p2, (0, 0, 255), 10)

cv2.namedWindow("draw", cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
while True:
    cv2.imshow("draw", m)

    ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)
    if ch == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i want to avoid `m = cv2.cvtColor(m, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` but neither `cv2.CV_8UC3` `np.uin32` works.

some hint?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this as `size`:

```
size = 200, 200, 3
m = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Basically what I did to find what arguments I need for the matrix is:

```
img = cv2.imread('/tmp/1.jpg')
print img.shape, img.dtype
# (398, 454, 3), uint8
```

But one could probably find it in OpenCV documentation as well.

Comment: where in the documentation please?

Comment: Hm, I can't find any official opencv docs on this, which states clearly that you have to do it this way, I guess it's a "common knowledge" that you need 3 layers/dimensions for a color image. However I was able to find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881926/create-a-new-rgb-opencv-image-using-python) SO question.