# creating Mat with OpenCV in python

Tags: python, java, opencv, mat

I am used to [Java's implementation of OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,int)). I want to create a `Mat` structure, fill data into it, extract a `submat` and then apply some image transform. In Java, I use:

```java
my_mat = new Mat(my_rows, my_cols, CvType.CV_8U);
my_mat.put(0, 0, my_data);
my_mat.submat(0, my_other_rows, 0, my_other_cols);
```

But I didn't find anything working in python's OpenCV. I found this link on the OpenCV forums: [cv2.CreateMat in python](http://answers.opencv.org/question/30037/cv2createmat-in-python/), <s>but the link is broken</s>

Answer (score 6):

Even though the question was asked a long time ago, this should help anyone looking for an answer today.

This should be applicable to opencv versions >= 2.X. In python, the opencv images are now represented as numpy arrays. So, a `Mat` object can simply be created as follows:

```py
cvImg = np.zeros((rows, columns, channels), dtype = "uint8")
```

Comment: it's **rows, then columns**

Answer (score 1):

**For OpenCV 1.x :**

You can use [CreateMat](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#createmat) to do that :

> Creates a matrix header and allocates the matrix data.

```
Python: cv.CreateMat(rows, cols, type) → mat
    Parameters: 
        rows – Number of rows in the matrix
        cols – Number of columns in the matrix
        type – The type of the matrix elements in the form CV_<bit depth><S|U|F>C<number of channels> , where S=signed, U=unsigned, F=float. For example, CV _ 8UC1 means the elements are 8-bit unsigned and the there is 1 channel, and CV _ 32SC2 means the elements are 32-bit signed and there are 2 channels.
```

The function call is equivalent to the following code:

```
CvMat* mat = cvCreateMatHeader(rows, cols, type);
cvCreateData(mat);
```

**For cv2 interface :**

The new cv2 interface for Python integrates [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays into the OpenCV framework, which makes operations much simpler as they are represented with simple multidimensional arrays.
here's a starting example :

```
import numpy as np, cv
vis = np.zeros((384, 836), np.float32)
h,w = vis.shape
vis2 = cv.CreateMat(h, w, cv.CV_32FC3)
vis0 = cv.fromarray(vis)
```

Comment: thank you, the problem is that I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateMat'`...

Comment: which version are you using cv / cv2?

Comment: I am using `OpenCV 3.0`

Comment: It looks like you doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710520/opencv-createimage-function-isnt-working) anyway.

Comment: It does not work. Could you improve your answer please?

Comment: **this answer is outdated** and doesn't even use the modern OpenCV API. ignore it.