# What is equivalent of cvCreateMat function in OpenCV2 using python3

Tags: python, c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am converting an old piece of code written in c/cpp into python. It uses cvCreateMat function. From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182774/creating-mat-with-opencv-in-python) I believe that cvCreateMat function is not supported in OpenCV2. I dont know how to do it using OpenCV2/numpy. OR all I need is the equivalent of the following line in python.

`cv::Mat a = cvCreateMat(3*numberOfMatrices, 6,CV_64FC1);`

Comment: just create a numpy array the shape and dtype you need

Comment: how about cv.CreateImage

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/30037/cv2createmat-in-python/ This should help you.

Comment: @Miki I dont know what will I put in type. If `numberOfMatrices` is 6 then I guess the `cvCreateMat` will create a matrix of 18 rows 6 columns, initialized with 0. I am also not sure do I need `np.array` or `np.matrix`.

Comment: @Spinkoo I want the equivalent because the later functions utilize this data. I believe the cvCreateMat is replaced by numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do

```
// the third 3 is so it has 3 dimensions which i suppose what you need
size = 3*numberOfMatrices, 6
img = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.float64)
```

this is  the correct format to create

Comment: Yes I think something similar but I found this [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) which gives a bit different format for it.

Comment: Will it not be `img = np.zeros((3*numberOfMatrices, 6), dtype=np.float64)

Comment: It works to create matrix of 0's but I am not sure if it is eqivalent of cvCreateMat? Do you know? If yes i will accept it as answer.

Comment: Yes it its the equivalent to do it in python you can call it with np.ones too if yo want

Comment: Hi Spinkoo please remove the last 3 from `size = 3*numberOfMatrices, 6, 3`. It should be `size = 3*numberOfMatrices, 6`