# Creating new image with OpenCV in Python not working

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create a new image of size 1920 x 1080 with opencv and currently do not care what color it is.
I am having trouble finding how to do this. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710520/opencv-createimage-function-isnt-working) however it is outdated and imports cv rather than cv2, which apparently does not contain CreateImage().

Comment: Use Numpy  ---   np.zeros((1080,1920,3), dtype=np.uint8)  --- will make a black image with 3 channels and 8-bits per channel per pixel. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html also see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html to make some other color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV in Python use `numpy.ndarray` as its data container. So if you want to create an 3 channels 8 bits image with all-zero pixels, just use `numpy.zeros([1920, 1080, 3], np.uint8)`